# How to view the content from script that loads from a web page

Tags: websites

I want to see what scripts web pages load into memory because sometimes they are malicious and I do not see what content or process is triggered.

Comment: Most browsers have builtin developer tools which let you inspect what's going on, including which scripts are loaded from which source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In google chrome browser,The Chrome Developer Tools (DevTools for short), are a set of web authoring and debugging tools built into Google Chrome. The DevTools provide web developers deep access into the internals of the browser and their web application.Using the console,debugging javascript,improving rendering performance, you can read more in [that link](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Example: see javascript loading 
`click right mouse -> Tab Network -> Check JS -> It display all javascript file what load`
More than CSS, IMG, Media, Font....etc

In Firefox browser, you can open debugger,set a breakpoint, inspect elements... by Firefox Developer Tools. Read more in that [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger)

In opera browser, Opera Dragonfly — our fully-featured suite of developer tools, designed to make your job easier. It’s just a right-click away. No install required.Futher more you can search opera dragonfly

Comment: In what browser? All of them don't have the same UI.

Comment: google chrome. I think mozilla firefox or the most browser. You can **inspect**. That's simple. Tell me which browser you're using?

Comment: I'm not trying to do this, I am just suggesting that you [edit] and add the information to your answer to make it better.

Comment: I know that i need to use the dev tools in my browser, but when i inspect it only the text is shown. I need to use some kind of debugging script in the console and set a break point.. but how.

Comment: @user7306345 ... you need to check more tabs in the Dev tools ...